# 3 sided triangle area calculator

Tags: java

For some reason when I input 4 , 6 and 7, I get the wrong area. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and it's driving me nuts. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CaclulateAreaTriangle{
   public static void main(String args[]){   
       
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the first side of the triangle:");
        int a= scanner.nextInt();
 
        System.out.println("Enter the second side:");
        int b= scanner.nextInt();
 
        System.out.println("Enter the third side:");
        int c= scanner.nextInt();
        if((a+b)>c && (a+c)>b && (b+c)>a)
          {
            int s=(a+b+c)/2;
            double area=Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
            System.out.println("Area of Triangle is: " + area);    
           }
         else  
            System.out.println("These Values Can Not Form a Triangle");
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. `s` is not a `double`. 2. Divide by `2.0` instead of `2` to use non-integer division.

Comment: This: `int s=(a+b+c)/2;` is int division, and so it will return an imprecise int result, where you, in fact, need a more accurate double result.

Comment: What other kinds of triangles are there than 3-sided?